# Problems with AngularJS $locationChangeStart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have a method:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) { 
    //......
}
```

But when I use Google Chrome browser, I have:

```
current = localhost:8080/index.html#/step1
next = localhost:8080/index.html#/step2
```

And when I user Internet Explorer, I have:

```
current = localhost:8080/index.html#/step2
next = localhost:8080/index.html#/step1
```

How to configure AngularJS, than in different browser I have:

```
current = localhost:8080/index.html#/step1
next = localhost:8080/index.html#/step2
```

Comment: could you explain more in your question? what exactly you wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

[Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) says

> The newState and oldState parameters may be defined only in HTML5 mode and when the browser supports the HTML5 History API.

The HTML5 History API is unfortunately [only available for IE >= 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=history).

I'm afraid you'll have to find another way if you have to support IE < 10...

Comment: But I'm using Internet Explorer 11